# Why am I getting this error when I use 'rackup' but not when I use 'ruby'

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra

I am new to Ruby and Sinatra, and I am attempting to finish this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/just-do-it-learn-sinatra-iv/

At the end of the tutorial, before deployment, the tutorial says "Before we move on to deploying the app, we should just check that everything is running fine on our local machine. This is done in a different way now that we have a rackup file."  It then instructs the student to enter "rackup" at the command line.  When I do so, then go to the 9292 local port specified in my browser I get the error:

```
DataObjects::ConnectionError at / file is encrypted or is not a database
```

But when I run my application by typing "ruby main.rb" in the same directory, the app works fine in my browser.  Is the tutorial wrong?  Am I fine to just deploy my app to Heroku as is?  Or do I need to get it working using the rackup command?

I am using sqlite3 1.3.9 and ruby 2.0.0

here is my 'main.rb' file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite3::memory:')

class Task
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,           Serial
  property :name,         String, :required => true
  property :completed_at, DateTime
  belongs_to :list
end

class List
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,           Serial
  property :name,         String, :required => true
  has n, :tasks, :constraint => :destroy 
end

Task.auto_upgrade!

List.auto_upgrade!

#checks integrty of models
DataMapper.finalize

#For using SASS
get('/styles.css'){ content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8' ; scss :styles }

get '/' do
  @lists = List.all(:order => [:name])
  slim :index
end

post '/:id' do
  List.get(params[:id]).tasks.create params['task']
  redirect to('/')
end

delete '/task/:id' do
  Task.get(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect to('/')
end

#this adds a button that toggles a checkmark on and off
#so you can check something off your list
put '/task/:id' do
  task = Task.get params[:id]
  task.completed_at = task.completed_at.nil? ? Time.now : nil
  task.save
  redirect to('/')
end

post '/new/list' do
  List.create params['list']
  redirect to('/')
end

delete '/list/:id' do
  List.get(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect to('/')
end
```

my config.ru file:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require './main'

DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

run Sinatra::Application
```

and my Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem "sinatra"
gem "datamapper"
gem "slim"
gem "sass"
gem "dm-postgres-adapter", :group => :production
gem "dm-sqlite-adapter", :group => :development
gem 'tilt', '~> 1.4.1'
```

I also have a config file in a .bundle folder that says

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

I'm not sure where to start.

My code is already different in a few ways than the final code posted at:
https://github.com/daz4126/Just-Do-It

because I have already had some errors that I had to make workarounds for.  Copy pasting the final code doesn't make it work.

Thanks in advance.  I have other files I can post, just figured the relevant files were these.

Comment: Sandbox the gems using Bundler and try it again and see if you get the same error, e.g. `rm -rf .bundle Gemfile.lock` then `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor` then `bin/rackup config.ru`.

Comment: @iain Thanks, I put these commands in, but after entering the last command, terminal says "bash: bin/rackup: No such file or directory". I also tried an absolute path to 'bin/rackup'

Comment: Are you in the project dir when you run it? The '--binstubs' option should have put a `bin` directory in the project dir, and in that will be all the executables from the gems, so `rackup` should be in there.

Comment: I am.  I am also getting an error `An error occurred while installing do_postgres (0.10.14), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install do_postgres -v '0.10.14' succeeds before bundling.`  after I do the bundle install, and even if I do the `gem install do_postgres -v '0.10.14'` I still get the same error after trying to bundle again

Comment: Which version of Bundler are you using? Also, if you use `--binstubs` and `--path vendor` then the gems installed by Bundler will be separated from the one installed by the `gem install` command. A lot of problems are caused by installing gems via `gem` *and* `bundle` which then conflict, so I sandbox them using the extra switches. If there aren't `bin` and `vendor` directories in the project dir, I'd reinstall Bundler for starters.